# Bizarre behaviour of lm() and predict.lm() depending on use of explicit namespace accessor

Tags: r, lm, predict, spline

I am interested in some disturbing behaviour of the `lm` function and the associated `predict.lm` function in R. The `splines` base package provides the function `bs` to generate b-spline expansions, which can then be used to fit a spline model using `lm`, a versatile linear model fitting function.

The `lm` and `predict.lm` functions have a lot of built-in convenience that take advantage of formulas and terms. If the call to `bs()` is nested inside the `lm` call, then the user can provide univariate data to `predict`, and this data will automatically be expanded into the appropriate b-spline basis. This expanded matrix of data will then predicted upon as usual.

```
library(splines)

x <- sort(runif(50, 0, 10))
y <- x^2

splineModel <- lm(y ~ bs(x, y, degree = 3, knots = c(3, 6)))

newData <- data.frame(x = 4)
prediction <- predict(splineModel, newData) # 16

plot(x, y)
lines(x, splineModel$fitted.values, col = 'blue3')
points(newData$x, prediction, pch = 3, cex = 3, col = 'red3')
legend("topleft", legend = c("Data", "Fitted Values", "Predicted Value"),
       pch = c(1, NA, 3), col = c('black', 'blue3', 'red3'), lty = c(NA, 1, NA))
```

As we see, this works perfectly:

[image]

The strangeness happens when one uses the `::` operator to explicitly indicate that the `bs` function is exported from the namespace of the `splines` package. The following code snippet is identical except for that change:

```
library(splines)

x <- sort(runif(50, 0, 10))
y <- x^2

splineModel <- lm(y ~ splines::bs(x, y, degree = 3, knots = c(3, 6)))

newData <- data.frame(x = 4) 
prediction <- predict(splineModel, newData) # 6.40171

plot(x, y)
lines(x, splineModel$fitted.values, col = 'blue3')
points(newData$x, prediction, pch = 3, cex = 3, col = 'red3')
legend("topleft", legend = c("Data", "Fitted Values", "Predicted Value"),
       pch = c(1, NA, 3), col = c('black', 'blue3', 'red3'), lty = c(NA, 1, NA))
```

[image]

The exact same results are produced in the second snippet if the `splines` package is never attached using `library` in the first place. I cannot think of another situation in which the use of the `::` operator on an already-loaded package changes program behaviour.

The same behaviour arises using other functions from `splines` like the natural spline basis implementation `ns`. Interestingly, in both cases the "y hat" or fitted values are reasonable and match one another. The fitted model objects are identical except for names of attributes, as far as I can tell.

I have been unable to pin down the source of this behaviour. While this may read like a bug report, my *questions* are

1. Why does this happen? I have been trying to follow through `predict.lm` but cannot pin down where the divergence occurs.
2. Is this somehow intended behaviour, and if so where can I learn more about it?

Comment: Another strange thing is that if you look at the coefficients from each model, they are the same, yet the predictions are different. By the way, you shouldn't create your data twice, because it will be different each time (unless you set the same seed each time). It doesn't make a difference here because the data are totally deterministic either way, resulting in the same model output, but better to set a seed and create the data only once.

Comment: You're right, it would have been better style to set a seed or re-use the data. But I wanted to emphasize that the second snippet is selt-contained and self-contradictory independent of the first -- there is no way the predicted value in the second plot should lie so far from the values fitted to the original data/

Comment: And yes, the coefficients are identical, along with all numerical content in the two model object. The issue comes in somewhere in the prediction step that uses combination of the "call" and "terms" elements of the fitted model object to automatically expand the new x value into a b-spline vector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the problem is that the model needs to keep track of the knots that were calculated with the original data and use those values when predicting new data. That typically happens in the `model.frame()` call inside the `lm()` call. The `bs()` function returns a class of `"bs"` and when making the model.frame, that column is dispatched to `splines:::makepredictcall.bs` to try to capture the boundary knots. (You can see the `makepredictcall` calls in the `model.frame.default` function.)

But if we compare the results

```
splineModel1 <- lm(y ~ bs(x, y, degree = 3, knots = c(3, 6)))
attr(terms(splineModel1), "predvar")
# list(y, bs(x, degree = 3L, knots = c(3, 6), Boundary.knots =  c(0.275912734214216, 
# 9.14309860439971), intercept = FALSE))

splineModel2 <- lm(y ~ splines::bs(x, y, degree = 3, knots = c(3, 6)))
attr(terms(splineModel2), "predvar")
# list(y, splines::bs(x, y, degree = 3, knots = c(3, 6)))
```

Notice how the second one doesn't capture the `Boundary.knots`. This is because of the `splines:::makepredictcall.bs` function which actually looks at the name of the call

```
function (var, call) {
    if (as.character(call)[1L] != "bs") 
        return(call)
    ...
}
```

When you use `splines::bs` in the formula, then `as.character(call)[1L]` returns `"splines::bs"` which does not match `"bs"` so nothing happens. It's unclear to me why this check is there. Seems like the method dispatching should be sufficient to assume it's a `bs` object.

In my opinion this does not seem like desired behavior and probably should be fixed. But the function `bs()` should not really be called without loading the package because functions like `makepredictcall.bs` don't be imported either so the custom dispatching for those objects would be broken.

Comment: Ah, excellent. It does seem strange that the "dispatching" there is done with a string comparison. Still seems odd that my particular prediction at x = 4 would be affected, considering my newly predicted point was not only within the boundary knots, but within the interior knots. The position of the Boundary knots shouldn't affect the estimation of such points.

Comment: Well done. That said, I think it'd be pretty important to know why the code's author included that initial check before concluding that it's undesirable and should be fixed.

Comment: @mb7744 It's not that odd -- as you dig into R's model-fitting machinery, you'll find that many many `formula` and `terms`-related operations use just that type of operation on character vectors deparsed and ultimately derived from the formula.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Right. I could see a user passing a `bs` object directly to a function so I can see why it's there. I guess the "problem" is really it doesn't also check for "splines::bs" or "splines:::bs"

Comment: Sure, but why not check the class of the object directly? Or is a string comparison necessary because all that is available at that stage  is a string literal of the call?

(It seems a better system would be to record the class/attributes of the  object in the call separately from the string `call`. Then for example, one could assign `B <- bs(..)` and then call `fit <- lm(y ~ B)` and be able to use `predict(fit, data.frame(x = 4))`... but it's too late in the game for that.)

Comment: @mb7744. Well, the check of the class already happened at dispatch. What it's trying to work around is the case where you do something like `b<-bs(x, knots=c(3,4)); lm(y~b)`.

Comment: But that doesn't work, does it? By "work" I mean allow the user to provide just the vector 'x', not the expanded form.

Comment: @mb7744 Well, i mean you can fit the model that way, but it does not make it easy to predict since there's nothing in the formula indicating where it came from. I'm sure there was some case out there that this was designed to avoid, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: @MrFlick One last point related to your answer: "But the function bs() should not really be called without loading the package because functions like makepredictcall.bs don't be imported either so the custom dispatching for those objects would be broken." I believe this is inaccurate, when one calls a function using `::`, the exported functions from that package *are* loaded, but not attached. (Thus the custom methods do work even without the package being attached.) That is why I was so surprised by the behaviour that inspired my question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be related to the boundary knot values in the 'predvars' attribute of the 'terms' part of splineModel.

If we call them splineModel_1 and splineModel_2

```
predict(splineModel_1, newData)
16
predict(splineModel_2, newData)
6.969746

attr(splineModel_2[["terms"]], "predvars") <- attr(splineModel_1[["terms"]], "predvars")

predict(splineModel_1, newData)
16
predict(splineModel_2, newData)
16

attr(splineModel_1[["terms"]], "predvars")
list(y, bs(x, degree = 3L, knots = c(3, 6), Boundary.knots = c(0.323248628992587, 9.84225275926292), intercept = FALSE))

attr(splineModel_2[["terms"]], "predvars")
list(y, splines::bs(x, y, degree = 3, knots = c(3, 6)))
```

As you can see the difference is in the Boundary.knots. The only other difference is that the intercept defaults to FALSE so that's probably not relevant. The Boundary.knots are taken from the min and max of x. As for it being set by one version of bs and not another, I can only assume this is a relic in the code of lm that looks for 'bs' and not 'splines::bs' to set the Boundary.knots correctly.

Comment: Well spotted noticing the differing boundary knots, but with respect to "a relic in the code of lm that looks for 'bs' and not 'splines::bs' to set the Boundary.knots correctly", note that there is no other `bs` function in base R. Calling my first snipped without the `splines` library attached results in an error.

Comment: @mb7744 Indeed. I'm speculating that there may have been a function called bs in the past (in base R or another common package) that made it a good idea to have splines::bs at the time.